# vue js how to copy value from textbox to div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i am trying to run function when button is clicked.

and `text box one value` should display in `div`

**Template code:**

```
<input v-model="textdata" type="text" class="w-full rounded">

<div class="bg-white h-10 w-full  ">{{textdata}}</div>

<button @click="getvalue" class="bg-green-800  rounded " >RECEIVE</button>
```

**VUSJS:**

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

function getvalue(){
    console.log(this.textdata)
    }

return{
    getvalue,
}

}

 
})
</script>
```

Right now it's showing data in console, but how can i show same data on div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define 2 refs and then update one of them from the other upon the click event

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const textarea = ref("");
    const text = ref("");

    function getvalue(){
      this.text = this.textarea
    }

    return{
        getvalue,
        text,
        textarea,
    }
  }

})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="textarea" type="text" class="w-full rounded">
  <div class="bg-white h-10 w-full">{{text}}</div>

  <button @click="getvalue" class="bg-green-800  rounded " >RECEIVE</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked, can you please tell will it work same if i have image file in input and i want to show that on div?

Comment: I believe it's possible. please consider creating a new question and I would love to help out (since it's a separate question from this)

Comment: i created new question please check.

Comment: The new question you have shared isn't with regard to the issue you have mentioned here in comments but I have given answers.